# How to build a chart in excel, such that the source file containing data can be changed interactively?

Tags: excel, charts, interactive

I have a directory with many excel files with numeric data. In each file the data is arranged in the same manner (the same column names, etc...). I am interested to build an interactive 
chart which will display the data according to the chosen file name. 
For example, the file name will be chosen from validation list in a drop down menu fashion. 
The question is how to specify the data range in the chart, such that it will change according to the name of the file that I choose.

I work with excel 2010 and don't have much experience with VBA programming :(
Thanks a lot,
Sasha

Comment: Thanks for this comment, didn't notice this option. Previously, I used to thank a person who helped me the most in the comments like this.

Comment: this is how stackoverflow works (and it works well btw :)) - you should also have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple solution (there may be more elegant ways but that's a first hint):

1. Copy the data from your files in the Sheets of your workbook, you can create references (see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-link-to-another-cell-workbook-or-program-HP005199514.aspx)) or automate copies through macros (just [STFW](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=excel+copy+data+from+a+workbook+to+another))
2. Create your validation list (for instance on `Sheet1`, cell `A1`). Let's assume this list contains: DataSource1, DataSource2, DataSource3.
3. Create [**Named Range**](http://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html) for every other Sheet you have and use **the same name as the one in your list** (DataSource1, DataSource2, DataSource3)
4. In the chart source of values, use this formula: `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$A$1)`

Hence, Excel will translate the source to the Named Range.
You could probably find solutions with vba too depending on your needs.

Regards,

Comment: JMax, Thank you for your answer. However, copying the files into one single file is not practical in my case. Each file contains about 3MB of data and there are several hundreds of these files. Moreover, new data is added to each file on a daily basis. Thus, I am looking for solution which will allow me to pull the data from the files without aggregating it in one file. I am reading now about indirect.ext function (http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/). There is a chance that it may help...

Comment: @Sasha: i can't see an easy way to create a chart with data from closed workbook without even *copying* or at least referencing data (with `INDIRECT` or VBA) in the other sheets of the Workbook containing the Graph. Please don't hesitate to post an answer if you find a solution.